# What would happen if we were to put a resistor at a junction?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

I am currently studying electrical circuits in high school, and at some point I wondered what would happen if we were to create three (or more) connections on a component and put it at a junction. For example, how would the resistance be measured if it was to be put at a junction. [image: Resitance at a junction]

If I was to put another resistance after the first one, would I consider them to be in series or parallel?
[image: Resistance at a junction with two other resistances]
"R" and "R1" (or R and R2) are not not separated by a junction, as "R" is placed on the junction. Therefore, we would expect R to be in series with R1 and R2. However, if it was to be the case then R2 and R1 would be in series with one another, while separated by a junction (what is not possible). Are the usual formulae applicable and if not how would you deal with such a set up?

I understand that we don't do this and that there does not seem to be any point. But I am curious of how things would be if we were to do this and to know if there is any interesting science this creates?

Comment: Can you please clarify the following sentence " "R" and "R1" (or R and R2) are not not separated by a junction as "R" placed on it but if it was to be in series, then R2 and R3 would be in series while separated by a junction (what is not possible) "? In particular can you define "R3"?

Comment: [Transistors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor) are a kind of component that has three connections. It can somewhat simplified be seen as a resistor whose resistance between two connections (*collector* and *emitter*) depends on the voltage over another pair of connections (*base* and *emitter*). One can mount a resistor "in parallel" over two connections or more "in series" with one connection.

Comment: @Matteo My apologies I wrote R3 while I should have written R1, I fixed this mistake. R1 and R2 are resistors of any value placed after the first resistance "R". They are here to investigate wether the first resistance R is in series or parallel to them, while being placed on the junction.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the resistance is the result of the geometry of component and the resistivity of the material it is made of. So for a simple wire you would have that the resistivity is

$$
R= \rho  \frac{L}{A}
$$

when the geometry is more complex you need to analyse the geometry more carefully using Ohms law in its less well known vector form

$$
\bar{E}=\rho \bar{J}
$$

a simple derivation of the wire resistance can be found on the wiki page about Ohm's law, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law. The general solution requires solving the poison equation and applying the continuity equation for the current. Some examples can be found here https://web.mit.edu/viz/EM/visualizations/coursenotes/modules/guide06.pdf

If on the other hand the resistor R in your drawings is in fact a complex collection of individual resistors or other components you can use Kirchhoff's laws, see
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws.

Answer (score 0):

In your first diagram, if the two wires to the right of the resistor are ideal wires (i.e. have zero resistance) then the current is the two wires is undetermined. We know from Ohm's law that the total current flowing round the circuit is $I = \frac V R = \frac {100} R$, and we know that the sum of the currents in the two wires must be equal to $I$, but there is no way to determine what the individual currents $I_1$ and $I_2$ are in the two wires. This is because the voltage drop across the two wires is zero, so any values for $I_1$ and $I_2$ will satisfy Ohm's law for these two wires.

In reality, of course, the wires will have some non-zero resistance so we in effect have the situation shown in your second diagram. In this case we still have $I_1+I_2 = \frac {100} R$. But now we can determine $I_1$ and $I_2$ because they are related by a second equation $I_IR_1 = I_2R_2$ which we get from applying Ohm's law to the two wires; the voltage drop across the two resistors $R_1$ and $R_2$ must be equal.